# Javafx webengine arbirtary error executing javascript

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a problem with webengine with javafx 2.2.5 running on swing app , so want to login to ebay with webengine, which I can do, the problem is sometimes it throws a javascript error when executing the click.This is a small percentage of the time, normally it works fine.
So lets say this code:

```
 final StackPane root = new StackPane();
 WebView browser = new WebView();
 WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
 final String url ="https://signin.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn";
 //load the url
 webEngine.load(url);
 final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);
 root.getChildren().add(browser);
 //addlistener for state
  webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {              
            Worker.State state = (Worker.State)t1;

            if(state==Worker.State.SUCCEEDED){
                         Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
                         Element u = (Element) doc.getElementById("userid");
                         u.setAttribute("value", username);
                         Element p = (Element)doc.getElementById("pass");
                         p.setAttribute("value", pass);
            //now execute the click, as the load succeeded the button should be clickable
            webEngine.executeScript("document.getElementById('but_sgnBt').click()");
            }   
}
});
```

Well most of the time it works, but sometime for unknown reasons it doesn´t, I also tried quite a few variations to see if I can reload the page and try again, but every time it give error the first time , the other calls like reload() and load(), continue with the same problem.
I tried this to:

```
final StackPane root = new StackPane();
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
String url ="https://signin.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn";
//load the url
webEngine.load(url);
 final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);
root.getChildren().add(browser);
//addlistener for state
 webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {              
            Worker.State state = (Worker.State)t1;

            if(state==Worker.State.SUCCEEDED){

                         Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
                         Element u = (Element) doc.getElementById("userid");
                         u.setAttribute("value", username);
                         Element p = (Element)doc.getElementById("pass");
                         p.setAttribute("value", pass);
            //now execute the click, as the load succeeded the button should be clickable
            try{
            webEngine.executeScript("document.getElementById('but_sgnBt').click()");
           }catch(Exception ex){
            webEngine.getLoadWorker().cancel();
            //with both is the same outcome
            //  webEngine.reload();
                webEngine.load(url);
           }
            }   
}
});
```

With this the code will go on loop if it fails the first javascript execution, it loads, succeeded and throw an error anyway, I tried to sleep the thread to see if the problem was that the page was not completely loaded, but that doesn´t seem to be the problem, as far has I can see when state is succeeded the page is loaded, correctly.
I´ve spent quite a few time with this, right now I have no more ideas about how to fix this or even what the problem is,to make matter worst I have to try a few time running the code until I get the error, which makes debug much harder.

The error in question is::

netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: 'null' is not an object at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)

So my question, does anyone have a clue about why this is happening?
Or a workaround to this issue?

Many Thanks

Comment: do you have a stack trace or error message of mentioned javascript error?

Comment: @Sergey Yes, netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: 'null' is not an object
 at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method), i think its because the page isn´t really loaded, so the execution of javascript fails, but i´m no expert at javascrip..

Comment: I found a workaround but still would like some other solution.My workaround consists of, if the browser fails in the log in (javascript), i basically destroy that instance and make a new one, has 90% of the time its fine, this should work, but is not a javafx solution and its not very pretty..

Comment: Update , no workaround , still the same thing, although i create a new instance in this case the webbrowser is contained in a JFrame..